# WPF binding to fields works

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

So as I always thought WPF only binds to  properties

But I  bound my textbox to a public field an it worked can you explain this to me ?

Here s my textbox XAML :

```
 <TextBox x:Name="afweh"  DataContext="Class1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="225,13,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding j}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="162"/>
```

and here s my field  :

```
public static class Class1
{
    public static string j="houmaaaaaaaaaaaani" ;
  //some code 
}
```

as you can see "J" is a field and not a property

Thanks.

Comment: You mean it compiles? I doubt that at runtime the TextBox shows "houmaaaaaaaaaaaani". In particular because `DataContext="Class1"` assigns the string "Class1" to the TextBox's DataContext, not an instance of Class1. So that class isn't even used in the binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant bind to either statics nor fields:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new Class1();
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    public static string j = "houmaaaaaaaaaaaani";
    public string J { get { return j; } set { j = value; } }
}
```

And in the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="afweh" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="225,13,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding J}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="162"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: turns out that was a    afweh.textbox=Class1.j;      that i forgot to delete lol sorry